# Oracle Virtualbox snapshots status

Tags: virtualbox

for the folks familiar with VM (Oracle Virtualbox) I have a question. I tried to figure out why the status of the snapshot sometimes is green and sometimes is red, see caps below.

Thanks a lot!

Green here:

[image: GREEN]

and sometimes red:

[image: RED]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, then:

- green with *play* triangle [image: play] means snapshot taken for running machine (called "online");
- red with *stop* square [image: stop] means snapshot taken for stopped machine (called "offline").

I usually take snapshots of stopped machines to avoid possible problems.

For details see: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/UserManual.pdf (ch. 1.10, 5.4, 8.6).

Comment: thanks a lot! That's what I thought but not true. I take the snapshots when Power Off not running/pause/saved. I waited for the ending process to clear the cache memory and then the snap is taken. I just took a snap in the save state and is green (current state - changed). Weird. I will look closely

Comment: probably I did not wait for enough to clear off the cache even if the guest status was Power Off.